# create Month as a header with CGMake in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I create 52 week button via CGMake as you can see in the picture:

This is my week view calender

and here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    int rows = 13, columns = 4 ;
UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 80*columns, 32*rows)];
int currentTag = 0;

for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {

        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed: 201.0/255.0 green: 201.0/255.0 blue:201.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
        button.tag = currentTag;
        currentTag++;
        [button.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
        [button.layer setBorderWidth: 0.5];
        if (x == 0 && y == 3) {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        } else if(x == 1 && y == 5) {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        } else if(x == 2 && y == 5) {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 

        } else if(y == 0) {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 
        } else if(y == 1) {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 

        } else if(y == 2) {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 
        } else if(y == 3) {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 
        } else if(y == 4) {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 
        } else if(x == 1 && y == 6) {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; 

        } else {


            //  [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        }


        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"W %d",currentTag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(80*x, 32*y, 80, 32); 
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonView addSubview: button];

    }
  }

// Center the view which contains your buttons
CGPoint centerPoint = buttonView.center;
centerPoint.x = self.view.center.x;
buttonView.center = centerPoint;
[self.view addSubview:buttonView];    

}
```

RightNow I want to have 12 month in this calendar and added 1 month as a header for each 4 weeks

I don't know How can I create this header with CGMake and put it in my loop

would you please help me

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve what you're looking for is using a UITableViewController with a 4-day cell for each row and a header view with the month name. Your approach is pretty brute-force and will eventually give you a lot of very-hard-to-solve bugs and low performance.

Comment: thansk but if i want to do this like a above code do you know how can I do that since I want to have it like a calendar but in table  I have just a row

Comment: Again, you could design each row in the table to hold 4 dates, then you'll get the calendar grid. The way it's designed right now - I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use custom cell for uitableview and set what are all the properties you need